Calling powershell single command in few lines
The below multistring powershell command:
(Get-Content "%FILE_PATH%") `
.Replace("      token1", "") `
.Replace("      token2", "") `
.Replace("      token3", "") | Set-Content "%FILE_PATH%" `

fails in first line with Replace:
    char:1
    + .Replace("      token1 ...
    + ~~~~~~~~
    Unexpected token '.Replace' in expression or statement.
        + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

but works if I put all lines in a single line (same failure behavior if I remove backticks). Given that a command is long, I want to put it into few lines. I also don't want introducing temporary variables.

piggy-backing off the posted answers, you don't need a backtick after the dot if it's being placed in a new line.
(this). that where that in a new line will still be read as part of the reference for the property. As for your current solution to your problem, using the RegEx -Replace operator may be more suitable for you here, since you can use the | (or) operator to specify multiple strings to replace.

It is as simple as putting the dot before the new line, backticks were never needed.

As an aside: To avoid confusion, in PowerShell code samples it is better to use, e.g., $FILE_PATH rather than the cmd.exe-style %FILE_PATH% as placeholder values; also note that - unlike in cmd.exe - variable references need not be enclosed in "..."

The Backtick Character, Followed by New-Line-Character, is a White Space.
According to the PowerShell Language Specification 3.0, Appendix B. Grammar, section B.1.3 White space, the backtick character, when at the end of a line, is a treated as a white space.  This behavior applies to PowerShell versions 5.1 and PowerShell Core (7.x):

whitespace:

Any character with Unicode class Zs, Zl, or Zp
Horizontal tab character (U+0009)
Vertical tab character (U+000B)
Form feed character (U+000C)
` (The backtick character U+0060) followed by new-line-character



This means that you can use the backtick to break a command into multiple lines ONLY at locations in the command where a white space character is allowed by PowerShell.
For example, since this is acceptable:
'This is a test'. Replace('a ', 'a successful ')

Then this is also acceptable:
'This is a test'. `
Replace('a ', 'a successful ')

But, since this fails:
'This is a test' .Replace('a ', 'a failed ')

Then this will also fail:
'This is a test'`
.Replace('a ', 'a failed ')

An alternative would be to use -Replace ... in place of .Replace(...):
'This is a test'  `
-Replace 'a ', 'a successful '


Good information to have (+1), though I'm surprised that the PowerShell language spec only calls an escaped newline whitespace, given that a newline by itself is also whitespace. It's just that the escaped form is needed to guarantee its interpretation as if it were intra-line whitespace (like a space char.), but at the end of lines that are syntactically incomplete even an unescaped newline functions like that.
Therefore the use of ``` in your "this is also acceptable" command is unnecessary (but tolerated).

(Get-Content "%FILE_PATH%"). `
Replace("      token1", ""). `
Replace("      token2", ""). `
Replace("      token3", "") | Set-Content "%FILE_PATH%" `


To spell it out: The key is to place the . at the end of the line being continued rather than at the start of the next. For syntactically incomplete statements, such as in the case at hand, ``` is not needed for line-continuation.
